# Filling cells with loop in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to fill cells with a for loop like this:

```
 For i = 1 To Target 
    Range("C" & i & ":C" & i ).Formula = "='Sheet1'!A" & i & "/" & "'Sheet2'!B" & i" 
 Next i
```

And I want to see that in the formula bar:

> ='Sheet1'!A1 & "/"  & 'Sheet2'!B1
>
> ='Sheet1'!A2 & "/"  & 'Sheet2'!B2
>
> ...

Unfortunately it's not working. If I try only the first part like that:

```
 For i = 1 To Target 
    Range("C" & i & ":C" & i ).Formula = "='Sheet1'!A" & i 
 Next i
```

This code results this fine, but this is not enough for me:

> ='Sheet1'!A1
>
> ='Sheet1'!B1
>
> ...

What is wrong with my frist code?

Comment: like this has not ever been asked before on the site...

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
   Range("C" & i & ":C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC1 & ""/"" & Sheet2!RC2"
```

Comment: What doesn RC1 mean? How it will iterate with "i" iterator like in my example ?

Comment: I figured out R means row and C columsn, but If i do this:
R & i & C2  doesn't work.

Comment: In your example you were using a1 and b1 , then a2 and b2 etc and my solution does this ( in c1, then c2 etc)

Comment: But instead of a1 or b1 i need ai and bi , beacuse it depending from the iterator. And I value can be 1 to any number

Comment: something else up?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with double quotes in a concatenated string, I sugest you remove as many as you can. Single characters can be referred to by their ASCII code number with the [Chr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262692.aspx). The `/` character is 47.

```
Dim i As Long, target As Long

With ActiveSheet
    target = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To target
       .Range("C" & i).Formula = "='Sheet1'!A" & i & Chr(47) & "'Sheet2'!B" & i
    Next i
End With
```

You do not have to increment through a range is the formula is constructed properly. Either an xlA1 or xlR1C1 reference style can be used (see [xlReferenceStyle enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlreferencestyle.aspx)).

```
Dim i As Long, target As Long

With ActiveSheet
    target = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'xlA1 style
    .Range("C1:C" & target).Formula = "='Sheet1'!A1/'Sheet2'!B1"
    'xlR1C1 Style
    .Range("C1:C" & target).FormulaR1C1 = "='Sheet1'!RC1/'Sheet2'!RC2"
End With
```

Note that an xlR1C1 style requires the [Range.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) instead of the [Range.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx).

Comment: None of them working. The problem is, that I want to see in the cell if I lookat the formula that:


='Sheet1'!A1 & "/" & 'Sheet2'!B1 


And if I look the value the cell looks like something that:
105/12  .

105 from Sheet1 A1 cell, / is the character and 12 is from Sheet 2 B2

These solutions you wrote doesn't do that, because _&_ and _"_ characters won't write in the cell formula, because VBA interpret that characters.